# How to style body in StyleX?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-in-js

In [StyleX](https://stylexjs.com/), how to style a body?

The body element that stays outside any React component, is usually styled using `useEffect`, but I can't figure out how to actually use that in StyleX.

There's nothing in the [documentation] about it (searched for "body" keyword).

Answer (score 0):

If the body element is not rendered by a component (which is the case with Next.js), then use a traditional CSS file to style it.

StyleX is made for styling components and keep those styles contained. You’re supposed to keep using traditional CSS for global styles and resets.